# Hibernate OnDelete Cascade(@ManyToOne) not working for MySql

Tags: hibernate, web-services, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have ManyToOne mapping and I wish to delete all the child elements upon deletion of Parent.Unfortunately @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE) is creating a foreign key constraint (on delete = restrict) which is a default one on the child table.

Entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "location_poc")
public class LocationPOC {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "contactname", nullable=false)
    private String contactname;

    @Column(name = "email", nullable=true)
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "phone", nullable=true)
    private String phone;

    @Column(name = "title", nullable=false)
    private String title;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "locationID", referencedColumnName = "locationID")
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)

    private Location location;
```

Create statement:

```
CREATE TABLE `location_poc` (
   `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `contactname` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
   `email` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
   `phone` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
   `title` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
   `locationID` int(11) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
   KEY `locationID_idx` (`locationID`),
   CONSTRAINT `FK65jm2e3enqcu1nd37x48l57it` FOREIGN KEY (`locationID`) REFERENCES `location` (`locationID`),
   CONSTRAINT `locationID` FOREIGN KEY (`locationID`) REFERENCES `location` (`locationID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Note: On delete cascade constraint is the one which I created manually while creating the table and other constraint created by hibernate.

I am not sure why ondeleteaction.cascade is not working.Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: did you have bidirectional onetomany and manytoone mapping

Comment: I can confirm this problem for hibernate with MySql/MariaDb even today - did you solve this problem somehow during the years passed?

Comment: I deleted the table and restarted the app. The hibernate did not create any foreign key constraint, So I manually created the foreign key with on delete cascade and it worked fine.
Hope it helps @MartinPeter

Comment: @MartinPeter, I solved it by using `@OneToOne` instead of to-many relations or it can be solved by using CascadeType.Remove in `@OneToMany` annotation instead of `@OnDelete`. Hope this will help somebody.

Answer (score 0):

Custom Dialect:

```
public class MySQLDialect extends MySQL57Dialect {
public MySQLDialect(){
    super();
}

public boolean supportsCascadeDelete(){
    System.out.println("--- supportsCascadeDelete() called.");
    return true;
}
}
```

Using via persistences.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
                         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_2.xsd"
         version="2.2">
<persistence-unit name="..." transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">

    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="ORM.DBSubsystem.MySQLDialect"/>
    </properties>

</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```